# Conditional Compilation in common unit depending from specific project?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, conditional-compilation

In Delphi XE2, I have a unit **MyUnit.pas** which is used by two different projects **ProjectA** and **ProjectB**.
**MyUnit** contains a statement `DoSomething;` (which is a procedure implemented in an other unit **OtherUnit.pas**).
Now I want to use **Conditional Compilation** to include `DoSomething` only in **ProjectA** compilation and *not* in **ProjectB** compilation, so to avoid **ProjectB** including/compiling **OtherUnit.pas** indirectly.
This MUST be **Conditional Compilation**, as a simple `if/else` statement obviously does not work for this purpose.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm a bit confused from what you ask here. Have you checked [`the help`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) for conditional compilation ? It's quite well described... Or, do you have any trouble with its implementation ?

Comment: Your statement that "_This MUST be Conditional Compilation, as a simple if/else statement obviously does not work for this purpose._" is wrong. You can achieve exactly the same effect without conditional compilation by using polymorphism. In fact I'd strongly recommend that polymorphism is usually the better way to solve your problem....

Comment: (cont.) A brief outline given limited comment space: **(1)** Define `DoSomething` as a virtual stubbed (empty) method in a shared unit. **(2)** Override it in `OtherUnit.pas`. **(3)** Each project creates the object that must be used by `MyUnit.pas`. **ProjectA** includes `OtherUnit.pas` and creates the object using that unit. **ProjectB** _doesn't_ include `OtherUnit.pas` and creates the object using the new shared unit. **(4)** In this way `MyUnit.pas` would only use the shared unit and not `OtherUnit.pas` but still get the benefit of its implementation in project that are allowed OtherUnit.

Comment: @CraigYoung I think DI might be a cleaner way to achieve this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Absolutely. But I suspect OP would be unfamiliar with the term so described it step 3... As best I could before running out of characters.

Comment: @user1580348, thank you for answering my comment. I'm really curious what problem did you have when you knew even the term *conditional compilation*... You wrote your post nicely but wouldn't be faster for you to search in help ? Or tell us what specific part you don't understand if you read help ?

Comment: @TLama My knowledge of conditional compilation in Delphi was only half-baked, now it has increased due to the help of the writers here, thanks to all! The Embarcadero help about conditional compilation is not so extensive, the people here like David and Graymatter should have written it! The Emba help lacks essential examples, like on this page here. I have a lot of professional experience in the field of Learning, and I can tell you that small essential examples are most effective for this purpose. It has to do with how the brain works, but there's not enough place here to explain...

Comment: Ok, just a quick statement: The process of translating an example (should be short) to a set of abstract rules which can be effectively applied later, strengthens the "links" between synapses in the brain, and therefore it is better memorized also in the long-term memory. Where memorizing abstract rules which are not generated internally by the brain is not very effective. In fact, to make it effective, one has to translate the rules into examples, which is trial-error, very error-prone without a guidance and takes several times longer than the first method.

Comment: @user1580348, I don't know much in this area (and I'm quite doubtful that someone can reliably measure something what you describe), but from my own experience I remember the best what I resolve by myself if we are at memory. Let it be, I was just wondering because in help there's even a very basic example (which could be better though)...

Comment: @TLama Modern neuroscience and learning theory are quite interesting. Try it out!

Comment: @user1580348, maybe. You might try to learn reading manuals. I know they are boring, but you'd find even the answer to your comment question *"when I make even only a small change in ProjectA, it does not work anymore. It only works again after a REBUILD, just Compiling does not work."*. In the manual is written: *"If you change a conditional symbol's status and then rebuild a project, source code in unchanged units may not be recompiled. Use Project > Build All Projects to ensure that everything in your project reflects the current status of conditional symbols."*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a conditional in one project, but not the other. For instance, you might define `CanUseOtherUnit` in the project options for project A, but not for project B.

Then you need to make the following changes to `MyUnit.pas`.

Put the `uses` clause that refers to `OtherUnit` inside an `$IFDEF`:

```
uses
  ... {$IFDEF CanUseOtherUnit}, OtherUnit{$ENDIF};
```

And then at the point where you call the function, again wrap the call inside an `$IFDEF`:

```
{$IFDEF CanUseOtherUnit}
DoSomething;
{$ENDIF}
```

Because the conditional is not defined in project B the compiler ignores the code inside the `$IFDEF` directives.

---

When you actively desire for a unit not to be used, the convenience of search paths becomes a weakness. It's just too easy for you to add units to the program without realising it. When you do not use search paths, and are compelled to add the source files to the project (.dpr file) then you cannot accidentally take a new dependency.

Comment: Thanks to both! BTW, when I would define the conditional value inside the source code, WHERE do I put this {$DEFINE CanUseOtherUnit}? At the beginning of the source file, in the unit file or in the project file? What is the logic here?

Comment: You need to put it in a place where it is seen by one project and not the other. The obvious place is in the project options. Gets stored to the .dproj file.

Comment: @user1580348 imho The .dproj file is an unholy mess, and I don't put things there if it can be avoided. An alternative for this situation is to put an include `{$I defines.inc}` at the top of `MyUnit.pas`. Then create a `defines.inc` file in each project's folder. And set any desired conditional defines in the appropriate include files.

Comment: @CraigYoung That works until the two projects are in the same folder, a not uncommon scenario. Project files would be fine if only Emba would move certain settings into a per-user file. I'm thinking of target platform and config. All it takes is to move them into per-user file and it's all good.

Comment: @David I agree `.dproj` would be fine **IF** done properly. You've mentioned some problems and I concede I'm not up to speed on all the latest fixes; so some of the ffg may have been resolved already: * Randomly inserted blank lines in `.dproj`. * Some settings collapsed into a single line of xml (making version comparisons a headache even with BeyondCompare). * Run parameters stored in `.dproj`?? * Environment variables stored in `.dproj`. * Option use debug DCUs stored in `.dproj`. These are off the top of my head. (Also I know Andreas wrote a utility to fix _some_ of these problems.)

Comment: @Craig I think most if not all those problems are still there. Conditionals are fine mind you.

Comment: Strange: Now, while using the conditional compilation, when I make even only a small change in ProjectA, it does not work anymore. It only works again after a REBUILD, just Compiling does not work.

Comment: Are you sharing DCUs between projects?

Comment: @user1580348 This is one problem with using conditional defines instead of polymorphism. (_Solve it by building DCUs to different folders per project_.) Others problems: * Conditional defines can interfere with code navigation and completion. * You cannot access conditional code without recompiling. So testing that code requires either a different project or: close app+change option+rebuild+rerun. * The problem extends to writing unit tests... You cannot cannot have a single test app test both variations of the unit. * Also each $define multiplies the total variation combinations: 2x2x2x2x2...

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this is a duplicate of something but I couldn't find an obvious one explaining the basic concepts. This is explained in the documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29).

You can use {$IFDEF} for this. You check for it with:

```
{$IFDEF MyValue}
{$ELSE}
{$ENDIF}
```

or for not defined:

```
{$IFNDEF MyValue}
{$ELSE}
{$ENDIF}
```

You then need to define the value. You can do this either in a source file with:

```
{$DEFINE MyValue}
```

or in your project options (Project > Options > Delphi Compiler).