# Delphi shared unit in two projects

Tags: delphi, module

I have two applications which partially have the same functions and it is inconvenient to change both apps with each update of those functions.

Is it possible to compile projects with one shared unit with shared functions? The unit will operate with components from both projects with identical names and classes. (So far I'm just always copying the same code between projects for shared functions).

I have those two projects joined in project group if this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible. In fact, it is even advisable to do this, partly because one of the most important rules of programming is [that you mustn't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy!

1. Copy the shared source file in a [probably new] folder dedicated to shared sources.
2. In the two projects folders, remove the shared file (.pas, .dfm (or .fmx) and .dcu)
3. Open the first project, if the shared file was explicitly included in the project, now the IDE complain about missing file and will remove it from the project. If it is not removed, remove it manually using Project Manager (Ctrl+Alt+F11 to see it if not visible).
4. Add the shared file explicitly in the project using Project Manager (Right click on the project and click "add existing" then select the source ou have copied at step one). Instead of adding the shared file explicitly, you can add the shared folder to Delphi library path (Menu / Options / Language / Delphi / Library / Library path). I prefer to add the shared unit explicitly to each project but this is a matter of taste.
5. Now you can build your project as usual.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it should be doable and your guide combined with this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127491/conditional-compilation-in-common-unit-depending-from-specific-project

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction on sharing units between different projects. They don't need to be in the same project group either.

That's exactly how 3rd party libraries and the Delphi runtime works.

Of course you must always keep in mind, that any change in these shared units will affect all projects that use them. If you fix a bug, it's automatically fixed in all projects, you just need to recompile these projects (good). If you introduce a new bug, it will affect all projects (bad).

And then there is the question where to put these units and how to handle them in SCM. If you use SubVersion, you can add them to the project sources as svn:external. Other SCMs probably offer similar functionality.